# Select website and its language in AlertDialog and save it

Tags: java, android

I need to load and save a website and its language in sharedpreferences. When I exit and then open the app, saved website and language load. I have used various ways, but cant achieve it. There is `String` and `int` not compatible with each other.  My simple code like this:

```
      private SharedPreferences prefs;
      private static final String SELECTED_ITEM = "SelectedItem";
      private SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPrefEditor;

  @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    else if (id == R.id.web) 
    final CharSequence[] items={"English","Arabic","Russian"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);

        builder.setTitle("Choose Website");
        builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
        });

        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, getSelectedItem(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                int website=current_page;

                if("English".equals(items[which]))
                {
                    webView.loadUrl("https://english.com");
                    website=("https://english.com");
                }
                else if("Arabic".equals(items[which]))
                {
                    webView.loadUrl("https://arabic.com");
                    website=("https://arabic.com");
                }
                else if("Russian".equals(items[which]))
                {
                    webView.loadUrl("https://russian.com");
                    website=("https://russian.com");
                }

                saveSelectedItem(website);
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

 private int getSelectedItem() {
      if (prefs == null) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    }
    return prefs.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM, -1);
}

  private void saveSelectedItem(int which) {
    if (prefs == null) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    }
    sharedPrefEditor = prefs.edit();
    sharedPrefEditor.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM, which);
    sharedPrefEditor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting a String to an int variable (website)

You should probably save the language as a preference (String). and then when you load up the app, read the language preference and determine the website from there.

something like below.

```
public String getWebsite(){

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    if (prefs == null) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    }

    String language = prefs.getString("Language", "English");

    String website = "";

    switch(language){
        case "Russian":
            website = "russian.com";
            break;
        default:
            website = "english.com";
    }

    return website;
}

private void saveSelectedItem(String language) {
    if (prefs == null) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    }
    sharedPrefEditor = prefs.edit();
    sharedPrefEditor.putInt("language", language);
    sharedPrefEditor.commit();
}
```

when you call save selected item, just pass in items[which] instead of which

Answer (score 0):

in `saveSelectedItem(website);`
You are passing a string and the method requires int

```
private void saveSelectedItem(int which) {
    if (prefs == null) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    }
    sharedPrefEditor = prefs.edit();
    sharedPrefEditor.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM, which);
    sharedPrefEditor.commit();
```

For saving your data in shared preferences 
i recommend to use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) 
i recommend to make a class for example

```
public class WebsiteData 
{
    @SerializedName("lang")
    @Expose
    private String lang ;
    @SerializedName("website")
    @Expose
    private String website;

    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(String lang) {
        this.lang= lang;
    }

    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website= website;
    }
}
```

When user select language create new object and set the language with the chosen language and the set the website with its corresponding value 
Then Turn object into String by Gson Like following :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String dataToSave = gson.toJson(WebsiteData);

String loadedString = getUserData(context);
WebsiteData loadedData = gson.fromJson(loadedString, WebsiteData.class);
```

to save and load data use the following methods :

```
public void saveUserData(Context context, String data) {
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(DATA_KEY, data);
    editor.apply();
}

public String getUserData(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedpreferences.getString(DATA_KEY, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i will try it